# Woocommerce Bookings - adding custom field to admin email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, woothemes

I am having a hard time figuring out how to add my new custom billing field into my admin notification email. I am not a php expert (by any means) so i'm not sure what I messed up or if it is because it's trying to append the field to the general woo commerce admin notification email or the one from the Bookings plugin.
My custom field is working fine on the billing page, it's just getting it into the admin email and preferably into the back-end admin order management area as well?

To be completely honest, I was working on this before Christmas and completely lost track of what and where I was doing.

Thank you in advance!

Here is what I have for code.

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('Referral Source').'</h3>';

    /**
     * Output the field. This is for 1.4.
     *
     * To make it compatible with 1.3 use $checkout->checkout_form_field instead:

     $checkout->checkout_form_field( 'my_field_name', array( 
        'type'          => 'text', 
        'class'         => array('my-field-class orm-row-wide'), 
        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'), 
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter a number'),
        ));
     **/
    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array( 
        'type'          => 'text', 
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'), 
        'label'         => __('How did you hear about us?'), 
        'placeholder'   => __('Please enter how you were referred to our clinic.'),
        'required'  => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

    }

/**
 * Update the user meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if ($user_id && $_POST['my_field_name']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_name', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']) );
}
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));
}
/**
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');
function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'Referral Source';
    return $keys;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

So here is where I am now. It seams to be working but I think I have a doubled function in there. I believe the last function is the one that is working for adding the custom field to my emails.

```
/**
 * Update the user meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if ($user_id && $_POST['my_field_name']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_name', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']) );
}
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Referral Source', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));
}
/**
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');
function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'Referral Source';
    return $keys;
}


// WooCommerce 2.3+
    function my_custom_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
        $fields['_some_field'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Referral Source' ),
                    'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'my_field_name', true ),
                );
        return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'my_custom_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );



add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
     $keys[] = 'Referal Source';
     return $keys;
}
```

Comment: You aren't saving any fields named `Referral Source`, therefore, there's nothing to display. I have a tutorial on [customizing the checkout](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) that should walk you through the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

This method was updated in WooCommerce 2.3, though it should be backcompatible to your approach. It looks like the key you are adding to the array on the `woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys` filter does not match the name of the meta key your have updated fall back to a basic array. like you have it, but your key doesn't match the meta key you've updated in the `my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta()` function.

Here's how to add keys to the email in WC 2.3+:

```
   // WooCommerce 2.3+
    function kia_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
        $fields['_some_field'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Some field' ),
                    'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ),
                );
        $fields['_another_field'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Another field' ),
                    'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ),
                );
        return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'kia_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: will this also work for the order emails driven by woo Bookings plugin?

Comment: So would this be correct based on that example? I apologize, My php isn't that great, (http://imgur.com/ZqeBKnr)

Comment: Does it work? That's the ultimate answer. If it doesn't do what you are aiming for then you can either edit your question to paste the new code you're trying or it the question merits it post a new question. A screenshot of code is hard to use. And if you aren't telling us what part is failing then it is hard to investigate.

Comment: Though from a brief glimpse, I think you need to revisit [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). You don't appear to be using the same `$meta_key` in the `update_post_meta` function as in the `get_post_meta` function.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm fairly new here. I tried posting the code in my example but I couldn't get the code mini-Markdown formatting to work. No the code unfortunately didn't work for me and i'm sure you are right that I have something wrong. I just don't know enough about php to figure it out even reading the wordpress docs. Thank you for your help though, I'll repost if I do sort it out

Comment: Paste your code, then select it all, then click on the 'code' button (the two {} brackets), which just indents everything.

Comment: I don't have that option when commenting though. I'm sorry I tried to read the help etc. I'm sup a noob lol. When I try to comment here I can't get it to work and it won't let me add more then a certain amount of characters. Should I post my fixed code in my question. Should I just post my own answer?

Comment: No worries. Avoid code in the comments if you can, it's perilously hard to read. I'd suggest you edit your question. Have you gone through my tutorial? In your edit, you should post all your code and identify where you are still getting stuck.